# Webview + scrolling issue + android

Tags: android, scroll, webview

I am trying to embedded a webview in a framelayout. my launch.xml is as shown below.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>   
</FrameLayout>
```

I have implemented the `WebChromeClient` and `WidgetViewClient`. I have implemented the `onTouchEvent` and passing the touch events to the `WebView`.

The problem i am facing is am not able to scroll inside the webview. For example, the content is some 5 lines then am able to see only 3 lines and not able to scroll.

The touch events go to `Webview`, first `action_down` and then `action_move`, am not able to get what wrong am doing??

I have this code also

```
mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Is there anything else i have to set??

I have checked by replacing the FrameLayout with Scr
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is an issue with scrolling webpages from file:///. The only solution I came up with was to use an innerscrolling in the local Webpages. For that I used a modified script as downloadable at http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 . The only modification I did was to set in the css the height and line-height of the header and footer to 0px and in the header top and bottom to 0px too. And it works. Maybe it will help you too.

@mdelolmo: Please stop posting any answers like that, it doesn't help to pick out things that have nothing to do with the issue itself. It makes no difference if a Layout is defined or not! And the same Problem he describes occurs when you use the exact code of the webview tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you just need one child element (the `WebView`), why do you need the `FrameLayout` parent tag?

And second, you don't need to handle, any touch events, it handles the scroll automatically and by default. Have you had a look to this [WebView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) tutorial?

Is there any specific reason why you can't do it like they say? If so, what it is? Are you trying to map any other touch events?

Comment: Hi,, I have checked the webview tutorial. I removed the FrameLayout but that didnt help in anyway.. I have done exactly same as in the tutorial still it doesnt work.. mWebView.loadUrl (url) ;  in this if i give the url as some "http://www.google.com" it works just fine, but when the url is "file://mnt/sdcard/abc.html"(which i get unzipping some package) it doesnt work. this issue has screwed me for last 10 days. if i save some page saved from browser and then try to load it as above it works again..

Comment: I think you're missing a slash when referencing the html:
file:// and your path /mnt/sdcard/abc.html . Would it work?

Answer (score -1):

let the scroll there and make the contents of the `webview` as `wrap_content` Like if it works